# Selenium: How do I start Chrome with RailsPanel Extension loaded?

Tags: ruby, selenium, google-chrome-extension, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

What is the right way to do this?

```rb
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new

  extension_path = '/Users/jill/Documents/rails_panel-master/rails_panel'

  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"args" => ['--load-extension=' + extension_path]})

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, http_client: client, desired_capabilities: caps )
end
```

Also, *--load-extension* with switches worked, but there is little documentation on [Chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) for it.

```rb
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new( app, :browser => :chrome, http_client: client, :switches => ['--load-extension=' + extension_path] )
```

Comment: The technique in the question (**-load-extension** works for selenium-webdriver (2.53.4), not selenium-webdriver (3.05). Upgrade to 3.05 to use the solution in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used the extensions feature so no guarantees, but a look at the selenium-webdriver source - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/profile.rb#L38 - shows #add_extension and #add_encoded_extensions methods on the Chrome::Profile object, so you can try something like

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new()
profile.add_extension(extension_path)
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, http_client: client, profile: profile)
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work - the recent changes in Selenium have apparently broken a lot of configuration options.

Comment: This works for selenium-webdriver (3.0.5)!  I needed to bundle update from selenium-webdriver (2.53.4).

Comment: Also this requires a .crx file which I packaged in chrome.  See, [Chrome Extension Packaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/packaging).  Thus extension path became     extension_path = '/Users/jill/Documents/rails_panel-master/rails_panel.crx'