# Trying to install extension from Chrome store through Capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium, google-chrome-extension, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara

Trying to install Chrome extension through capybara test, but unable to achieve in Ruby

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-keep-chrome-extens/lpcaedmchfhocbbapmcbpinfpgnhiddi

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
  extension_path = 'https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sticky-notes-just-popped/plpdjbappofmfbgdmhoaabefbobddchk'
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new()
  profile.add_extension(extension_path)
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, http_client: client, profile: profile)
end
```

Tried with this but still dnt get success.

Comment: have you tried with something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/41497345/1033737 ?

Comment: Well, in Java it would be something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788590/how-to-install-plugin-while-launch-the-chrome-browser/49791640#49791640